# Implementing a generic DbContext service

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a generic interface which I want to implement in my code all round though the implementation may vary at some inheritance level.Why I'm doing this is because I have been writing this code for every single project I have been making and I'm bored of writing the same code with some little or no tweaks all the time.

I created this interface:

```
/// <summary>
// A generic interface for implementing the basic database operations.
// This interface can easily be implemented with custom user logic.
// The KId generic parameter is the primary key of the associated entity and the TEntity
// refers to the entity type.
// </summary>
// <typeparam name = "K" > The primary key of the entity.</typeparam>
// <typeparam name = "TEntity" > The type of entity.</typeparam>
public interface IGenericEntity<K, TEntity>
{
    // ........Definition codes...............
}
```

Though I can implement this in all my Service Implementation classes at different levels but I may be writing some things which are the same in the other Service Implementations.

I now decided to create this class called `GenericEntityImplementation` which I will Implement the IGenericEntity.

```
    public class GenericEntityImplementation<K, TEntity, TDbContext> : 
        IGenericEntity<K, TEntity> where TDbContext : DbContext
    {
        private readonly TDbContext _DbContext;

        public GenericEntityImplementation(TDbContext DbContext)
        {
            _DbContext = DbContext;
        }

/*1 */  public virtual async Task<OperationResult> DeleteAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression)
/*2 */  {
/*3 */      Task TaskResult = await _DbContext.Set<TEntity>().RemoveRange<TEntity>(expression);
/*4 */      if (TaskResult.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
/*5 */      {
/*6 */          return new OperationResult()
/*7 */          {
/*8 */              Message = "",
/*9 */              ReturnObject = null,
/*10*/              Status = OperationStatus.Deleted,
/*11*/              Succeeded = true
/*12*/          };
/*13*/      }
/*14*/  }
    }
```

`K` is the key type
`TEntity` could be the database class or rather database table to be scaffolded
`TDbContext` is of type `DbContext` as can be seen above.

As can be seen above I have passed a virtual DbContext into the class which I want to perform all the database operations at this layer.But since I've been trying, but as can be seen on line 3, the editor shows me that my code has some problems (underlined red).

My question is can someone explain to me how I can tell the DbContext passed to the class the type of entity I am trying to refer to at any instance like I can do in the code below?

```
public class ViewDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public HotelDbContext(DbContextOptions<HotelDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<View> Views { get; set; }
}


public class ViewsService
{
    private readonly ViewDbContext _DbContext;

    public GenericEntityImplementation(ViewDbContext DbContext)
    {
        _DbContext = DbContext;
    }

    public virtual bool Any()
    {
        return _DbContext.Views.Any() ? true : false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since we can't see your editor, can you include the error that is shown on line 3?

Comment: `? true : false` is redundant. It provides no benefit over simply calling `.Any()`, especially when the method calling it has the same name.

Comment: Yea but it's simple. All my codes have been purged here. You can be kind by just copying and pasting them in a single namespace and everything work out

Answer (score 0):

As was commented above the error I was receiving on the editor was:
The 'TEntity' must be a reference type in order to use it as a parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'DbContext.Set()'
But after that, something sparked into my head and I included this line at the top and everything works perfectly now.
`where TEntity : class`

```
public class GenericEntityImplementation<K, TEntity, TDbContext> : 
        IGenericEntity<K, TEntity> where TDbContext : DbContext where TEntity : class
{
}
```